# Cakephp find query issue

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.1

I am doing a find on a model as shown below however the SQL being generated is wrong due to which I am getting incorrect results.

```
$bookings = $this->Booking->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Booking.created BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours')),
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 hours'))
        ),
        'OR' => array(
            'Booking.payment_status' => 3,
            'Booking.payment_status' => 2
        )
    )
));
```

WHERE condition being generated by this find is (as shown by cake debugkit)

```
WHERE `Booking`.`created` BETWEEN '2013-03-27 11:01:57' AND '2013-03-27 23:01:57' AND `Booking`.`payment_status` = 2
```

And the where condition I am trying to create is

```
WHERE `Booking`.`created` BETWEEN '2013-03-27 11:01:57' AND '2013-03-27 23:01:57' AND (`Booking`.`payment_status` = 2 OR `Booking`.`payment_status` = 3)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here. Quick help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A frequently made PHP beginner mistake - using a key in an array more than once:

```
    'OR' => array(
        'Booking.payment_status' => 3,
        'Booking.payment_status' => 2
    )
```

It should read

```
    'OR' => array(
        array('Booking.payment_status' => 3),
        array('Booking.payment_status' => 2)
    )
```